# How can I tie a Terraform resource to an instance's lifecycle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform

I am trying to set up an ALB using Terraform and a spot instance, for a non-prod development workspace. The spot instance is created, but upon attempting to use the instance in the `aws_alb_arget_group_attachment`, I receive an error:

```
* aws_alb_target_group_attachment.ui_servers: Error registering targets with target group: InvalidTarget: The following targets are not in a running state and cannot be registered: '[id]'
        status code: 400, request id: [id]
```

This persists even if I add a `depends_on` directive to the attachment:

```
depends_on = ["data.aws_instance.workspace_gz"]
```

If I re-run the `terraform apply`, it works, so it really is just a lifecycle problem. How can I instruct the attachment to wait until the instance is healthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. What you ought to do is create the spot instances within an [autoscaling group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#using-with-spot-instances) for the spot instances and attach the ASG to the target group.